# How to keep all rows which are duplicates in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, if-statement, filter

I'm trying to accomplish this task with one line of code.  I want to groupby-->filter-->condition.

In Python/Pandas, I'm trying to display duplicates based on the 'full_name' column.  If there aren't any, then I want to display 'None'.

I tried this line of code, but it gives me invalid syntax:

`mktg_table = mktg_employees.groupby('full_name').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1 else 'None')`

[examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pEXj.jpg)

Comment: Please explain better what you are trying to do. groupby should follow with a function such as .sum()

Comment: Trying to filter a DataFrame to only return rows where there is a duplicate in the 'full_name' column.  If there are no duplicates, then return 'None'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you do not have MRE if have created a test data and the solution below works for that:

for not duplicate cases:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' :[1,2,3,4],'full_name' : ['ab','cd','ef','gh']})
df.shape

if df[df.duplicated(subset=['full_name'])].shape[0]>0:
    print(df[df.duplicated(subset=['full_name'], keep=False)])
else:
    print("None")
```

output:

```
"None"
```

for duplicate cases:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' :[1,2,3,4],'full_name' : ['ab','cd','ef','ab']})
df.shape

if df[df.duplicated(subset=['full_name'])].shape[0]>0:
    print(df[df.duplicated(subset=['full_name'],keep=False)])
else:
    print("None")
```

output:

```
   id full_name
0   1        ab
3   4        ab
```

Comment: Note that the user asked for both duplicates to remain in the output

Comment: yes Adding "keep =False", Thanks for the catch

Comment: It does capture both now. Thanks. Please upvote my answer if it makes sense. New here trying to earn reputations so I can post comments

Comment: Please do not solicit upvotes - that's against the T&C.

Answer (score 1):

See for example the following data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['Tim', 'Tim', 'John'],
                  "Age": [2, 4, 6]})
print(df)

   Name  Age
0   Tim    2
1   Tim    4
2  John    6
```

You can use this to retain dupicates:

```
df = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset='Name', keep=False)]
df
```

The output would be:

```
  Name  Age
0  Tim    2
1  Tim    4
```

If the 'None' output is important:

```
if (df.empty):
    print ('None')
```

Comment: That is not what I asked, but thanks for trying to answer.  I do not need to drop duplicates, I need to display the rows.  However, if there are not any duplicates in the 'full_name' column, then I want to return the word 'None'.

Comment: You are not clear enough. Please post example of your data and expected output

Comment: Thanks.  I added my expected output as an image in my original question.

Comment: See updated answer above

Answer (score 0):

```
data={'col1':['A','A','B','C'],'col2':[2,3,4,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df1=df[df.duplicated(subset='col1',keep=False)]

if df1.shape[0]==0:
    print("Empty")
else:
    print(df1)
```